# Pass and show data from ListView to TabView Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I have ListView with user list. My controller have event listener on user tap which opens new view (TabView), where I want to show detailed information about user in TabView container template,  but it doesn't displays anything.

Controller:

```
Ext.define('HockeyTeamManagementSystem.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        UserList: 'userlist',
        Users: 'users',
        UserDetails: 'userdetailtabs'
    },

    control: {
        "#UserList": {
            itemtap: 'onListItemTap'
        },
        "tabpanel": {
            initialize: 'onTabpanelInitialize'
        }
    }
},

onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var user = Ext.create("HockeyTeamManagementSystem.view.UserDetailTabs", {
        title: record.data.name +" "+ record.data.lastname,
        record: record
    });
    this.getUsers().push(user).setData(record.data);
},
```

TabView:

```
Ext.define('HockeyTeamManagementSystem.view.UserDetailTabs', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias: 'widget.userdetailtabs',

requires: [
    'Ext.tab.Bar',
    'Ext.XTemplate'
],

config: {
    activeItem: 1,
    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: false
    },
    tabBar: {
        docked: 'bottom',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            pack: 'center'
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Information',
            iconCls: 'info',
            tpl: [
                'name: {name}'
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Statistics',
            iconCls: 'star'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Payments',
            iconCls: 'compose'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some hours of testing different things I realized that I simply need to set data from `onListItemTap` function to TabView items:

```
refs: {
    UserInformationTab: '#UserInformationTab'
},

onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var user = Ext.create("HockeyTeamManagementSystem.view.UserDetailTabs", {
        title: record.data.name +" "+ record.data.lastname,
        record: record
    });
    this.getUsers().push(user);
    this.getUserInformationTab().setData(record.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the data in the container and not in the view itself.

```
{
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Information',
            iconCls: 'info',
            name: "info",
            tpl: [
                'name: {name}'
            ]
}
```

In the controller:-

```
refs: {
   infoContainer: 'container[name="info"]'
}
```

Now set the data:-

```
onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var user = Ext.create("HockeyTeamManagementSystem.view.UserDetailTabs", {
        title: record.data.name +" "+ record.data.lastname,
        record: record
    });
    this.getUsers().push(user);
    this.getInfoContainer().setData(record.data);
}
```

Comment: I have tested Your suggestion, but it doesn't worked. However I found solution by myself. Anyway thank you!